# Create NumericAxis with config param 'reverse' in Ext4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

With Ext3.3 we can use config param 'reverse' to create NumericAxis. I want to know how to do that with Ext4.

Following is a part of code with 3.3 :

```
xtype: 'linechart',
    store: st_rep_spkey_rank,
    xField: 'check_date',
    yAxis: new Ext.chart.NumericAxis({
        reverse: true, // ### here
        maximum: 100,
        minimum: 1,
        majorUnit: 20,
        minorUnit: 10,
        displayName: 'Rank'
    }),
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        displayName: 'keyword1',
        yField: 'rankG',
        style: {
            color:0x9999FF
        },
```